# kotlin gradle build generates graphql schema class in netflix package not my specified package

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, graphql, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a multi-module project (submodules: application and functional-tests). I have 3 build.gradle.kts files (one is under root directory, one is under application and one is under functional-tests). Now, I am running the command "./gradlew -p application clean bootJar". The issue is that the graphql schema files under my "application/src/main/resources/schema" folder are generating classes under package "com.netflix.dgs.codegen.generated", not the one I specified "com.my.package". Below is my application build.gradle.kts file.

```
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.Input
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.register

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot")
    id("com.netflix.dgs.codegen") version "5.6.3"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral() // Add Maven Central repository
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:3.0.6")
    implementation("io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config:2.3.5")
    implementation(group = "software.amazon.jdbc", name = "aws-advanced-jdbc-wrapper", version = "1.0.0")
    implementation(group = "org.postgresql", name = "postgresql", version = "42.5.0")
    implementation(platform("com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-platform-dependencies:5.4.2"))
    implementation("com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-pagination")

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2") // Add JUnit Jupiter dependency
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2") // Add JUnit Jupiter engine dependency
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-platform-dependencies:5.4.2")
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2020.0.6")
        mavenBom("io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws:2.3.5")
    }
}

sourceSets {
    named("main") {
        java {
            srcDir("application/src/main/java")
        }
        resources {
            srcDir("application/src/main/resources")
        }
    }
}

open class GenerateJavaTask : DefaultTask() {
    @Input
    lateinit var schemaPaths: List<String>

    @Input
    lateinit var packageName: String

    @Input
    var generateClient: Boolean = false

    @TaskAction
    fun generate() {
        // Task action
    }
}

tasks.named("build") {
    dependsOn("generateJava")
}

tasks.register<GenerateJavaTask>("generateDgsJava") {
    schemaPaths = listOf("application/src/main/resources/schema")
    packageName = "com.my.package"
    generateClient = true
}
```

UPDATE: I think the tasks I wrote above did NOT take any impact. Because if I remove the last three blocks (the defn of GenerateJavaTask, tasks.named("build") & tasks.register), it will still generates the dgs generated class into that netflix package.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've misconfigured a few things here;

You are trying to register a new task named `generateDgsJava` of Type `GenerateJavaTask` by doing the following;

```
    tasks.register<GenerateJavaTask>("generateDgsJava") {
        schemaPaths = listOf("application/src/main/resources/schema")
        packageName = "com.my.package"
        generateClient = true
    }
```

However, you don't need to register such a task because `dgsCodegen` already has an existing task named `generateJava`.

Also, you've asked your `build` task to depend on the existing `generateJava` task, by the following lines;

```
    tasks.named("build") {
        dependsOn("generateJava")
    }
```

This is the reason why, when you build - (even after removing the last few blocks that attempt to register the custom task) - the classes still get generated to `dgsCodegen`'s default package/directory.

**SOLUTION:**

1. Remove your custom `GenerateJavaTask` it's not needed at all.
2. Simply supply `generateJava` task with your arguments as;

```
    generateJava {
        schemaPaths = ["application/src/main/resources/schema"]
        packageName = "com.my.package"
        generateClient = true
    }
```

This should generate the classes in your specified package/directory.